# Service locator pattern and logged in user

Tags: c#, design-patterns, service-locator

I'm adjusting my web application layers in a way to make the code more testable.

Currently the UI talks to a service locator passing in an interface, this returns the appropriate object based on that type:

```
ServiceLocator.Get<ISomeService>().ListStuff(arg1, arg2);
```

Internally, services are instantiated with an instance of `IServiceContext` and cached.

```
private static Lazy<IDictionary<Type, object>> _services = new Lazy<IDictionary<Type, object>>(GetServices);

public interface IServiceContext
{
    IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    IUser CurrentUser { get; internal set; }

    ILogProvider Log { get; }

    ICacheProvider Cache { get; }

    IProfilerProvider Profiler { get; }
}

public LogService(IServiceContext serviceContext)
  : base(serviceContext) { }
```

I'm happy with the concept and it appears to be rugged enough, my only issue is I want to make the current logged in user available in the `ServiceContext` but unsure the best way to achieve it.

My thoughts travel along these potential options:

1. Keep a simple method in the `ServiceLocator` that handles getting the users session and injects it into the services as requests for them come in.
2. Move getting the current user out of the `IServiceContext` and into the `ServiceBase` base class of each service.
3. Stop doing this and make each service that needs a user dependent on it.

I appreciate any suggestions, I understand this question my not be in the true spirit of the site.
I have managed 4 days of trial and error to get to this point, just need the last piece of this puzzle.

Comment: Not a fan of ServiceLocator, but....I think 2 or 3 are better than 1 as a solution. If this were a web context and I were using IoC, I would probably inject `IUser`'s via the constructor, essentially adopting your #3 choice. It's probably the easiest way of testing it, to.

Comment: I think you're right.  I've checked what actually needs this property and worked out the balance between how could exist there and whether its actually needed has answered this.  I suppose I was hoping for a lightbulb moment.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably many solutions, and I'm not fully sure I understand your question but I'll try to help anyway.

Whenever I need the current user I make a call to static utility class right in the context of the code that uses it.  This way I eliminate the possibility of stale information.

You could make a class that implements `IUser` like

```
class User : IUser {
  private System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity;

  public User() {
    this.identity = identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
  }

  public string UserName { get { return this.identity.Name; } }
}
```

And then maybe:

```
public class ServiceContext : IServiceContext
{
    IUser CurrentUser { get { return new User(); } }
}
```

Comment: That's kind of what I had but I've just refactored a lot of the code to move away from utility methods as they were hindering the tests.  Thanks for your time & suggestion though.